# What are the implications of a JPA entity implementing Spring Security UserDetails?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA entity called `Member`. I would like for this entity to **implement Spring Security `UserDetails`** and **implement a custom JPA-based `UserService`.**

Before doing so, I have a few points of concern that I would like to sort:

- The `Member` entity has got quite a few properties. Can the fact that `Member` now implements `UserDetails` and is therefore stored into HttpSession (see `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`) **impact session usage significantly**?
- Can I retrieve the currently logged in `Member` by just calling: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();` and **expect all its properties to remain synchronized properly when they are updated elsewhere**?

Answer (score 2):

```
impact session usage significantly?
```

No.

```
expect all its properties to remain synchronized properly when they are updated elsewhere?
```

No, you'll have to manage that yourself ..., ie when you update it somewhere, make sure you also update the instance in memory :

```
Member member = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
member.setYourField(yourValue); //
```

Comment: Thanks for your input NimChimpsky. Ummm, this is not really feasible for a large app. Is there not a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: @balteo no, the principal gets added to context on login, any changes after that you'll have to do yrself